# UWidgetComponent not showing details in Blueprint editor

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Why are none of the `overheadDialogueWidgetComponent` details available to edit in the blue print editor?

header:

```
class ABasePaperCharacter : public APaperCharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
private:
    UDialogueComponentWrapper* dialogueComponentWrapper;
...
```

cpp:

```
ABasePaperCharacter ::ABasePaperCharacter ()
{
    this->dialogueComponentWrapper = NewObject<UDialogueComponentWrapper>();
    this->dialogueComponentWrapper->SetUpDialogueComponents(FObjectInitializer::Get(), this->GetRootComponent());
...
```

header:

```
UCLASS()
class UDialogueComponentWrapper : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_BODY()    
public:
    void SetUpDialogueComponents(const FObjectInitializer& objectInitializer, USceneComponent* componentToAttachTo);
private:
    UPROPERTY(Instanced, EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Dialogue", Meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = true))
    UOverheadDialogueWidgetComponent* overheadDialogueWidgetComponent;

...
```

cpp:

```
void UDialogueComponentWrapper::SetUpDialogueComponents(const FObjectInitializer& objectInitializer, USceneComponent* componentToAttachTo)
{
    this->overheadDialogueWidgetComponent = objectInitializer.CreateDefaultSubobject<UOverheadDialogueWidgetComponent>(objectInitializer.GetObj(), TEXT("Dialogue widget component"));
    this->overheadDialogueWidgetComponent->AttachToComponent(componentToAttachTo, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);
}
```

header:

```
UCLASS()
class ECDD_API UOverheadDialogueWidgetComponent : public UWidgetComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()    
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are exposing this component to Blueprints, it shouldn't be private. They must be protected or public in order to be exposed to BP (still you can use them from code). Imagine BP with `APaperCharacter` as a parent class. UE will create it's own C++ class deriving from `APaperCharacter` and tries to show you it's own properties. And since your component is private, this generated class doesn't see it, so it is not visible in a Details panel.

I believe that UE will also warn you during C++ compilation that fields marked with `UPROPERTY(..)` should not be private.

Comment: "They must be protected or public in order to be exposed to BP" - actually they don't. It would be horrid architecture if that was true hehe. (see: Meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = true))

I did however test to give you the benefit of the doubt. Unfortuantely it didn't work.

Thank you so much for the help though!

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Well, I'm not sure - based on discussion here https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?2125-UPROPERTY-best-pratices-question-(public-private-protected), Engine contributor says it can't be and another high ranked person says it could.

Answer (score 0):

Warning, there are no answers here, only defeat...

**ABasePaperCharacter:**

```
UCLASS()
class ECDD_API ABasePaperCharacter : public ABasePaperCharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    ABasePaperCharacter()
    {
        this->dialogueComponentWrapper = CreateDefaultSubobject<UDialogueComponentWrapper>(TEXT("Dialogue component wrapper"));
        this->dialogueComponentWrapper->AttachToComponent(this->GetCapsuleComponent(), FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);
        this->dialogueComponentWrapper->SetUpDialogueComponents(FObjectInitializer::Get(), this->dialogueComponentWrapper);
    }
private:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Dialogue", Meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = true))
        UDialogueComponentWrapper* dialogueComponentWrapper;
}
```

**UDialogueComponentWrapper - Notice the USceneComponent inheritance:**

```
UCLASS()
class UDialogueComponentWrapper : public USceneComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
public:
    UDialogueComponentWrapper();
    void SetUpDialogueComponents(const FObjectInitializer& objectInitializer, USceneComponent* componentToAttachTo)
    {
        this->overheadDialogueWidgetComponent = objectInitializer.CreateDefaultSubobject<UOverheadDialogueWidgetComponent>(objectInitializer.GetObj(), TEXT("Dialogue widget component"));
        this->overheadDialogueWidgetComponent->AttachToComponent(componentToAttachTo, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);
    }
private:
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "Dialogue", Meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = true))
        UOverheadDialogueWidgetComponent* overheadDialogueWidgetComponent;
};
```

**UOverheadDialogueWidgetComponent:**

```
UCLASS()
class ECDD_API UOverheadDialogueWidgetComponent : public UBaseWidgetComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
};
```

All of the above ends up with this:

[image]
[image]

I still had the issue of the component not showing details inside its details panel, but atleast I could now change the details.

I still have no idea why I cannot see the component's properties in the detail panel... but atleast I can continue to make my game.

Comment: Hi again! Today I experienced the same problem as you. IDK why my C++ based LightComponent stoped showing properties, but since I had no usages of that component in BP and only a few references in code, I **renamed property** and guess what? Now I can see all properties. I also noticed that I saw reference to that property in *class defaults*, but it was *NULL*. If it suits you, you can try this too.

Comment: For me, renaming the Mesh and then rebuilding the project did the job. Thanks @PavelPájaHalbich for pointing out.